# Usage of the relative pronoun "dont"

Tags: grammaire, sens, traduction

> Le mois passé, le roi du Bahreïn a procédé au remplacement de quatre ministres **dont** deux membres de la famille royale.

I'm not sure how to properly understand the way the relative pronoun *dont* is used in this quote. As far as I know, it's usually translated into English as either *whose* or *that*. However, Google Translate translated it for me as *including*. Literal translation would render the sentence almost meaningless: *Last month, the king of Bahrain replaced four ministers whose two members of the royal family*. That doesn't sound right. Help me out please.

Comment: It's probably best not to interpret *dont* as a relative pronoun here, but rather as a preposition. (This usage probably did grammaticalise from a relative construction but synchronically it doesn't behave as one)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Of which** would be the appropriate translation in this case:

> *Original text*: Le mois passé, le roi du Bahreïn a procédé au remplacement de quatre ministres **dont** deux membres de la famille royale.
>
> *My translation*: This past month, the king of Bahrain has proceeded with the replacement of four ministers, two **of which** are members of the royal family

Further reading: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont

Comment: Please see my comment under another answer, which I was composing while you were posting your equally good answer.

Comment: @Papa Poule I'd argue that my suggested translation would *almost* hold also in English without the verb "are", would you agree?

Comment: Unrelated, but your rendering "Le mois passé" as "This month" & especially your use of the present "are" got me thinking that my use of the past "were" could be ambiguous (ie, are those two no longer royals?), so I now would go with "being" in my version to avoid that possible ambiguity. Back to the issue, although I would still expect to hear or see some form of the verb "to be" in there, after repeating/re-reading it many times, I can certainly at least agree that it would almost work in English without "are/being" (& even that it might be perfectly fine (perhaps a question for ELU?).

Answer (score 4):

In this case, *including* is the right translation. The two members of the royal family are included into the four ministers being replaced.

Comment: Why is it the right translation?

Comment: @user69786 Because the others don't make grammatical sense? It can be hard to say *why* something is correct. This is one of the meaning of *dont*, and in this sentence it works and the others don't, so it must be this one.

Comment: @user69786 The other ones are very different grammatically. When *dont* means "whose", it's follow by a verbal group or a clause. When it's just followed by a nominal group, it means *including*.